# Constructing a function that declares some other function inside it's body?

Tags: maxima

Sometimes I need to use a declaration of a function inside another function. For example, I made the following in Mathematica:

> [image]

Ie: There is a function f and when I compute f[Cos], it declares h as Cos[x]. Observe that I can't do the same by computing f[x] because it does not recognize $x$ as a function, although I can circumvent that by using Mathematica's notation for pure function: f[#&], now it works perfectly fine.

I noticed I can do the same with Maxima:

> [image]

Although I don't know how to do the f[#&] in Maxima. Ie: Tell Maxima "x" is a function just as I did in Mathematica. Is there a way to do the same in Maxima? Also If I try to compile:

> [image]

Without asking it to compute g(x), f won't work in the same way it worked before. It's not clear to me why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:=` always defines a global function, even if it's within another function or block. As it stands, when you call `f` twice, the second definition of `g` clobbers the first one -- you can't have two different `g` functions.

I think what you want is an unnamed function, `lambda([x], ...)`. The tricky part is that the body of `lambda` is not evaluated, so when you write `lambda([x], y(x))`, the value of `y` doesn't appear in the result. There are a few different ways to achieve that; I'll describe one way using `subst`.

`subst('y = something, lambda([x], y(x)))` constructs an unnamed function and then pastes `something` into it, replacing `y`. The result is `lambda([x], something(x))` which I think is what you want.

To put this in the framework you outlined,

```
(%i3) f(x, y) := block ([g: subst ('y = y, lambda ([x], y(x)))], [g, g(x)]);
(%o3) f(x, y) := block([g : subst('y = y, lambda([x], y(x)))], [g, g(x)])
(%i4) f(1/2, cos);
                                                   1
(%o4)                    [lambda([x], cos(x)), cos(-)]
                                                   2
```